# Combine different types of features (Text classification)

Tags: python, text, classification, nltk

I'm doing text classification task I faced a problem. 
I've already selected the 1000 best feature collection using bag-of-words approach. Now I want use another features based on Part-of-Speech, average word length etc. After I want to combine these features together. How can I achieve it 
I'm using Python, NLTK, Scikit packages. This is my first python project so code maybe not very good.

Thanks in advance,

```
    import nltk
    from nltk.corpus.reader import CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
    import os
    import numpy as np
    import random
    import pickle
    from time import time
    from sklearn import metrics

    from nltk.classify.scikitlearn import SklearnClassifier
    from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB,BernoulliNB
    from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression,SGDClassifier
    from sklearn.svm import SVC, LinearSVC, NuSVC

    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    def intersect(a, b, c, d):
        return list(set(a) & set(b)& set(c)& set(d))

    def find_features(document, feauture_list):
        words = set(document)
        features = {}
        for w in feauture_list:
            features[w] = (w in words)
        return features


    def benchmark(clf, name, training_set, testing_set):

        print('_' * 80)
        print("Training: ")
        print(clf)
        t0 = time()
        clf.train(training_set)
        train_time = time() - t0
        print("train time: %0.3fs" % train_time)

        t0 = time()
        score = nltk.classify.accuracy(clf, testing_set)*100
        #pred = clf.predict(testing_set)
        test_time = time() - t0

        print("test time:  %0.3fs" % test_time)

        print("accuracy:   %0.3f" % score)
        clf_descr = name
        return clf_descr, score, train_time, test_time

        #print((find_features(corpus.words('fantasy/1077-0_fantasy.txt'),feature_list)))
    path = 'c:/data/books-Copy'
    os.chdir(path)
         #need this if you want to save tfidf_matrix
    corpus = CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader(path, r'.*\.txt', 
                                                  cat_pattern=r'(\w+)/*')
    save_featuresets = open(path +"/features_500.pickle","rb")
    featuresets = []
    featuresets = pickle.load(save_featuresets)
    save_featuresets.close()

    documents = [(list(corpus.words(fileid)), category)
                 for category in corpus.categories()
                 for fileid in corpus.fileids(category)]

    random.shuffle(documents)

    tf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', min_df = 1, 
                         stop_words = 'english', sublinear_tf=True)
    #documents_tfidf = []
    top_features = []
    tf = TfidfVectorizer(input= 'filename', analyzer='word',
                         min_df = 1, stop_words = 'english', sublinear_tf=True)

    for category in corpus.categories():
        files = corpus.fileids(category)
        tf.fit_transform( files )
        feature_names = tf.get_feature_names()
        #documents_tfidf.append(feature_names)
        indices = np.argsort(tf.idf_)[::-1]
        top_features.append([feature_names[i] for i in indices[:10000]])
        #print(top_features_detective)

    feature_list = list( set(top_features[0][:500]) | set(top_features[1][:500]) | 
                         set(top_features[2][:500])  | set(top_features[3][:500]) | 
                         set(intersect(top_features[0], top_features[1], top_features[2], top_features[3])))


    featuresets = [(find_features(rev, feature_list), category) for (rev, category) in documents]  
training_set = featuresets[:50]
testing_set =  featuresets[20:]
results = []
for clf, name in (
                          (SklearnClassifier(MultinomialNB()), "MultinomialNB"),
                          (SklearnClassifier(BernoulliNB()),   "BernoulliNB"),
                          (SklearnClassifier(LogisticRegression()), "LogisticRegression"),
                          (SklearnClassifier(SVC()),   "SVC"),
                          (SklearnClassifier(LinearSVC()),   "Linear SVC "),
                          (SklearnClassifier(SGDClassifier()),   "SGD ")):
    print(name)
    results.append(benchmark(clf, name, training_set, testing_set))

indices = np.arange(len(results))
results = [[x[i] for x in results] for i in range(4)]

clf_names, score, training_time, test_time = results
training_time = np.array(training_time) / np.max(training_time)
test_time = np.array(test_time) / np.max(test_time)



plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
plt.title("Score")
plt.barh(indices, score, .2, label="score", color='navy')
plt.barh(indices + .3, training_time, .2, label="training time",
                 color='c')
plt.barh(indices + .6, test_time, .2, label="test time", color='darkorange')
plt.yticks(())
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.subplots_adjust(left=.25)
plt.subplots_adjust(top=.95)
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=.05)

for i, c in zip(indices, clf_names):
    plt.text(-15.6, i, c)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: What is your question? It is unclear what you are asking, and just dumping a bunch of code is not helpful. Most of the above is likely irrelevant to your question.

Comment: I see too many questions in one go. Pick one and ask it using a [mcve]. Then move on to your new question (after trying it yourself first).

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I've already combined two different algorithms using FeatureUnion and Pipeline.  pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('text_features', FeatureUnion([
        ('vect', vect),  # extract ngrams from roadnames
       # ('num_words', Apply(lambda s: len(s.split()))), # length of string
        ('ave_word_length', Apply(lambda s: np.mean([len(w) for w in s.split()]))), # average word length
    ])),
    ('clf' , clf),   # feed the output through a classifier
])

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with combining features of different types (in fact it's generally a good idea for classification tasks). The NLTK's API expects features to come in a dictionary, so you just need to combine your feature collections into a single dictionary.

This is the answer to the question you asked. If there is a problem with your code which you need help with but did not ask about, you should probably start a new question.